# На эмуляторе не появляется окно запроса доступа к аккаунту ВК

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-vksdk

На эмуляторах не появляется окно запроса доступа к аккаунту и подтверждения. Просто темнеет экран, немного поработал прогресбар и всё.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На реальном телефоне всё работает хорошо. Но при нажатии на "Скрыть уведомление", вылетает ошибка 403.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста, что не так

Answer (score 1):

## В первом случае

Скорее всего у Вас на эмуляторах не установлены **Google Apps**.
Установите их, скачав [Google Apps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Gapps).
Далее распакуйте их в директорию, например, *gapps*.
Далее Вам следует запустить такие команды в [adb](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=383300):

```
adb shell rm /system/app/SdkSetup*  # удаляем пакеты, которые сбрасывают настройки при запуске эмулятора
adb push ./gapps/system/ /system/  # копирование системных приложений
adb ls /tmp  # смотрим название типо android-...
adb pull /tmp/android-.../system.img  # если выведет ошибку, посмотрите в папке android-... файл, похожий на system.img(расширение *.img и много весит)
cp system.img ~/.android/.../tablet.../  # я ничего не знаю о Вашем эмуляторе. Скопируйте system.img в папку с эмулятором.
```

Перезапускаем эмулятор и вуаля.(Может не сработать, т.к. Вы не указали версии эмулятора и всю остальную информацию)

## Во втором случае

Либо у Вас выключен **js**(включить можете в настройках), либо, если не сработает, обратитесь в [службу поддержки ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/support?act=home).